# How to find the parent page of partial page in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial page, `_Person.cshtml`, that is being shown as modal window in my `MainPage1.cshtml` and `MainPage2.cshtml`. I have this code inside the `ready` handler of `_Person.cshtml` partial page:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    //some code here
})
```

How can I know from which parent page the modal is shown? Based on the parent page, I want to construct the URL and take some action.

Comment: Are you using an `iframe`?

Comment: Partial views in ASP.NET MVC are rendered inline - not as iframes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could have your parent pages set a global variable using some javascript at the top, that your partial page could read from. Something like this might work:

**MainPage1.cshtml**

```
<script>
    mainPageName = 'MainPage1';
</script>
```

**MainPage2.cshtml**

```
<script>
    mainPageName = 'MainPage2';
</script>
```

**_Person.cshtml**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    console.log(mainPageName);
});
```

Mind that this would clutter the global namespace, and a better solution would be to do this in the _Layout.cshtml using the name of the current controller and/or view. But this will get you started.

A better solution would be to pass a `Model` object to the Partial view, containing the name of the parent page. This is more in line with the architecture of ASP.NET MVC.

**MainPage1.cshtml**

```
@Html.Partial("Person", new { ParentPage = "MainPage1" } )
```

**_Person.cshtml**

```
console.log("@Model.ParentPage");
```

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this you could put an identifying attribute on an element of the `MainPageX.cshtml` which you can read from the partial view. Here's an example using an `id` on the `body`:

```
<body id="mainpage1">
    <!-- your content -->
</body>
```

Then in the partial:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if ($('body').is('#mainpage1')) {
        // do something...
    } else if ($('body').is('#mainpage2')) {
        // do something else...
    }
})
```

Comment: The `body` element is located in the `_Layout` most times, so it would require some additional magic... But it is a good idea to use the `id` attribute!

Comment: Thanks. Using the `body` was just an example, you could put the attribute on any element that's available in the `MainPage.cshtml` and use the appropriate selector in the partial view.

Answer (score 0):

While calling the modal url from the parent page ,pass the name of the parent to controller and store that in ViewBag which we can access in partial cshtml.

So you will get the name of parent page on partial page.